# angular-cli build is not supporting to other (/posts) then root path (/) directly

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have create a build for angular2 project with angular-cli using **ng build** and it creates **dist** folder. When I run build with other web server it working fine for root path (http://127.0.0.1:8887) and allow me to access other path(like /posts)through application. But when directly access  the path **for eg.** http://127.0.0.1:8887/posts form browser, it gives me entry not found message. There is no error in console and it seems it's not loading index.html, when directly access with other then root path.

Comment: Ideally it should work. check for any any logical error or share that code fragment.

Comment: have you setup you deployment based on environments? if yes, then this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/847) seems to be related

Answer (score 1):

You are hosting the application via a separate web server at that point. You must customize that server to serve the root application for unknown routes which will permit the application to handle the routing client-side rather than having it being handled in the server.

So if you navigate to `[app root]/foo` your web server should return `[app root]` and then the angular application will be responsible for showing the content associated with the `foo` route.

There are instructions on the web for configuring different web servers to handle/manage SPA (single-page application) configurations.

You do not see this issue when debugging via `ng serve` because the `webpack-dev-server` (being used under the hood) is configured to support this server-side routing to the app root.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the file name change.  They changed one of the files that gets generated in the build process from "inline.js" to "inline.bundle.js"

Comment: What would be the solution for that?